# Disable list item while animating

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

So when I click a list item in my ListView it gets animated. The problem is that when it's animating I can still click it and this is undesirable. I'm using nineOldAndroids and to disable the ListItem I do:

```
set.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                     v.setClickable(false);
                      v.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    v.setClickable(true);
                    v.setEnabled(true);
                } 

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
```

setClickable behaves strangely: it does let me click the list item for a brief time after the animation starts and after the animation ends it won't let me click it anymore (even though I set it to true). And setEnabled doesn't work at all.

**How can I disable a list Item while an animation is running?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the adapter isEnabled(int position) method return false while the animation on that item is going on.

add this to your adapter

```
Set<Integer> disabledItems;
private void setRowEnabled(int position,boolean enabled){
    if(enabled){
        disabledItems.remove(position);
    }else{
        disabledItems.add(position);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

    return !disabledItems.contains(position);
}
```

And call the setRowEnabled from the onAnimationStart onAnimationEnd of your Animation

Comment: And how exactly do I do that?

Comment: It worked, thanks. But you need to init the Set private Set<Integer> disabledItems = new HashSet<Integer>();

Comment: I left that to you :) didn't want to also write the adapter constructor